# calculate the number of values in a column as a percentage using apply

Tags: r, apply

my data frame:

```
data <-structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
    col2 = c(NA, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, NA, 10L, 11L, 12L), col3 = c(6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, NA), col4 = c(9L, 10L, NA, 
    12L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), col5 = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, NA, 20L), GROUP = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), col6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    col7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), col8 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), col9 = 10:18), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to output each value from a column and calculate its number and how much it is in percentages for col9 and col10

I use `apply` this way:

```
k <- paste(apply(data[,c(9,10)], 2,table),apply(data[,c(9,10)], 2, prop.table))
```

and connect them into a cell

```
k <- apply(k,2,paste,collapse="\n")
```

but as a result I get an error
apply(k, 2, paste, collapse = "\n") :dim(X)
must have a positive length

UPDATE:
what I expect to get

```
new_data<-structure(list(col8 = "1 - 3 (33.3%)\n4 - 1 (11.1%)\n5 - 1 (11.1%)\n6 - 1 (11.1%)\n7 - 1 (11.1%)\n8 - 1 (11.1%)\n9 - 1 (11.1%)", 
    col9 = "1 - 0 (0%)\n10 - 1 (11.1%)\n11 - 1 (11.1%)\n12 - 1 (11.1%)\n13 - 1 (11.1%)\n14 - 1 (11.1%)\n15 - 1 (11.1%)\n16 - 1 (11.1%)\n17 - 1 (11.1%)\n18 - 1 (11.1%)"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function `f` that does the job for one column, and use `lapply`.

```
f <- \(x) {
  tx <- table(x)
  px <- proportions(tx)
  paste(sprintf('%s - %s (%s%%)', names(tx), tx, round(px*100, 1)), collapse='\n')
}

lapply(data[9:10], f)
# $col8
# [1] "1 - 3 (33.3%)\n4 - 1 (11.1%)\n5 - 1 (11.1%)\n6 - 1 (11.1%)\n7 - 1 (11.1%)\n8 - 1 (11.1%)\n9 - 1 (11.1%)"
# 
# $col9
# [1] "10 - 1 (11.1%)\n11 - 1 (11.1%)\n12 - 1 (11.1%)\n13 - 1 (11.1%)\n14 - 1 (11.1%)\n15 - 1 (11.1%)\n16 - 1 (11.1%)\n17 - 1 (11.1%)\n18 - 1 (11.1%)"
```

Note, that `prop.table` is an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility, use `proportions` instead.